# EF Core 2.0 Unable to Determine Relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core

I just recently upgraded my solution/project(s) from .NET Core 1.1 to 2.0, including EntityFramework Core.  I am now getting an error I never got from EF Core 1.1.

"Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'InsurancePolicy.Person' of type 'Person'."

Class/Entity definition is below.

```
public class InsurancePolicy
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "InsuranceCompanyId" )]
    public InsuranceCompany InsuranceCompany { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int InsuranceCompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "PersonId" )]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "PolicyHolderId" )]
    public Person PolicyHolder { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid PolicyHolderId { get; set; }

    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

If I remove the Person/PersonId property, I just get the same error but on a different entity/property.  Something else is going on or the way this is done in EF 2.0 changed.  This worked fine with EF 1.1 and I was able to run my migration and deploy the database.  After the upgrade to 2.0, I cannot make any calls to my DbContext without getting the above error.

Comment: Can you show the other part of the relationship, i.e. `Person` class and relevant fluent configuration if any.

Comment: It's a known but within EF 2.0.  They are tracking it here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9180.

Comment: Wow, I was thinking EF Core 2.0 is **stable** and **recommended** (at least this is what the documentation says)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah, I think this is a pretty major bug to release into the wild.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9180) within EF 2.0.

The work around for now is to explicitly define the relationship using the Fluent API.

For example (from the link provided):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Relation>(e =>
    {
       e.HasOne(r => r.AccountManager).WithMany(u => u.AccountManagerRelations).HasForeignKey(r => r.AccountManagerId);
       e.HasOne(r => r.SalesManager).WithMany(u => u.SalesManagerRelations).HasForeignKey(r => r.SalesManagerId);
    });
```